# General formula for finding covariance of monomials of multivariate random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, covariance, nonlinear

Suppose that we have independent random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3$ which are gaussian multivariate distributed with a mean of zero vector and a diagonal covariance matrix. $X=[X_1,X_2,X_3] \tilde{} N(0, diag(C))$

Now, I want to work in a higher dimensional space and transform $[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ into the composition of monomials such as $[(X_1^aX_2^bX_3^c), \forall (a,b,c), \in \mathbb{N}^3 ,\exists k \in \mathbb{N}, a+b+c = k]$ In this case, I need the covariance matrix of the monomials. How could I obtain it from $diag(C)$?

Comment: Are the $X_i$ individually _vector_ random variables? or just (univariate) Gaussian random variables? If the former, what is meant by $X_1^a$? If the latter, then $E[X_1^aX_2^bX_3^c]=E[X_1^a]E[X_2^b]E[X_3^c]$ since $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are _independent_, and since they are Gaussian, we have that $$E[X_i^m] = \begin{cases}0, & m~\text{odd},\\\sigma_i^m(m-1)!!, & m~\text{even},\end{cases}$$ which can be applied to the problem. (Note that $!!$ is not the factorial but the double factorial function.)  Also, $\sigma_i^2 = C_{i,i}$ in your chosen notation.

Comment: I guess the former. More precisely $X=[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ is multivariate Gaussian random variables and hence X_1, X_2 and X_3 are all individually univariate Gaussian random variables (as linear combinations of the components of the multivariate gaussian random vars have to be univariate gaussian). As for $X_1^a$, it is simply some power of the first component of X.

Comment: Your comment reveals that what you have in mind is the _second_ interpretation that I suggested: $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are three **independent** zero-mean (Gaussian) random variables and it is $X=[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ that enjoys a multivariate Gaussian distribution (with covariance matrix $C$ that is a _diagonal_ matrix. Thus, all my suggestions above apply. I will also add that if $a+b+c=k$ is an odd integer, then at least one of $a,b,c$ is necessarily odd, and so $E[X_1^aX_2^bX_3^c]=0$. When $k$ is an even integer, $E[X_1^aX_2^bX_3^c]$ is nonzero only when all of $a,b,c$ are even integers.

Comment: I see, I guess your suggestion implies off-diagonal elements of the transformed multivariate gaussian will be all zero hence the new covariance matrix will be diagonal as well. The nonlinear mapping I tried to formulize in my question can transform the multivariate gaussian $X=[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ into (multivariate Gaussian?)  $X'=[X_1^k, X_1^{k-1}X_2, X_1^{k-1}X_3, ...]$. in this case the covariance between the components having the same $X_i$ (but potentially with different powers) should not be zero, should it? Sorry for my notational mistakes.

Comment: @Dilip has made excellent suggestions.  Further observe that you can easily rescale all the $X_i$--the scaling factors contribute to the monomials in obvious, easily calculated ways--thereby reducing your question to one about moments of *independent standard Normal variates.* To answer that, you only need to know the moments of the standard Normal distribution. They are easily obtained from its moment-generating function (or even recursively from the moment definition, upon integrating by parts).

Comment: @bfaskiplar There are _numerous_ misunderstandings in your writings. There is _no_ transformation of any kind going on and no new covariance matrix being computed. $[X_1^k, X_1^{k-1}, \cdots,]$ is **not** a vector of Gaussian random variables, and the covariance is essentially irrelevant. Recite the following _mantra_ 3 times: If $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are _independent_ random variables, then so are $g_1(X_1), g_2(X_2),\ldots$ _independent_ random variables. That $E[X_1^aX_2^bX_3^c]=E[X_1^a]E[X_2^b]E[X_3^c]$ follows from the **independence** of $X_1^a, X_2^b, X_3^c$ (repeat the _mantra_ 3 times!)

Comment: ... and has _nothing_ to do with Gaussianity or multivariate Gaussianity or for that matter, covariances.

Comment: @DilipSarwate you said in your comment that $X=[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ is multivariate gaussian. If so, we can talk about its covariance right? and what I do is to transform the triples from this distribution into n-tuples and represent this as a new distribution (with apparently some cov matrix defined between its components pairs) as $[X_1^k, X_1^{k-1}]$. All I want to know is to obtain the covariance matrix for this new distribution. Think about how affine transformations on multivariate gaussians change the covariance matrix. What I do is not affine transformation but some nonlinear transformation

Comment: Could you please, pretty please, just write down one _specific_ question without using _any_ symbols such as $a,b,c,k$ etc. For example: "How do I find the covariance matrix of $[X_1^3, X_2^2, X_3^5]$ when $X_1, X_2,X_3$ are _independent_ zero-mean Gaussian random variables with variances $\sigma_i^2$?" Or "How do I find the covariance matrix of $[X_1^3X_2^4X_3, X_1^3X_2^2X_3^3, X_1X_2X_3^6]$ when $X_1, X_2,X_3$ are _independent_ zero-mean Gaussian random variables with variances $\sigma_i^2$?" Do not mention multivariate Gaussian or transformation or similar notions that I do not understand

Comment: yes, what you said after 'Or' is pretty much what I want. "How do I find the covariance matrix of $[X_1^3X_2^4X_3,...]$ when $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are independent zero-mean Gaussian random variables with variances $\sigma_i^2$?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an answer to the following question:

> Given $n$ independent Gaussian random variables $X_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$, what are the means, variances, and the covariance
>   of the random variables
>   $\displaystyle Y= \prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{a_i}$ and 
>   $\displaystyle Z= \prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{b_i}$ where
>   the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are nonnegative integers.

The keys to this question are

1. The independence of the $X_i$'s makes various *powers* $X_i^{t_i}$'s also independent random variables and consequently
   $$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{t_i}\right] = \prod_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i^{t_i}
   \right].
   \tag{1}$$
2. Since the $X_i$ are zero-mean Gaussian, we have that for positive
   integers $t$,
   $$E\left[X_i^t\right] = \begin{cases} 0, & t~\text{an odd integer},\\
   \sigma_i^t\cdot(t-1)\cdot(t-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1, & t~ \text{an even integer}.\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

It follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that 
\begin{align}
E[Y] &= \prod_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i^{a_i}\right]\\
&= \begin{cases} 0, & \text{at least one} ~a_i~\text{is an odd integer},\\
\prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{a_i}\cdot(a_i-1)\cdot(a_i-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1,
&\text{all}~a_i~ \text{are even integers}.\end{cases}\tag{3}
\end{align}
A similar result holds for $Z$.

Since all the exponents of the $X_i$ are *even* integers in
$Y^2 = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{2a_i}$, we readily see that
$$E[Y^2] = \prod_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^{2a_i}\cdot(2a_i-1)\cdot(2a_i-3)\cdots 3\cdot 1 \tag{4}$$
which together with $(3)$ gives the variance of $Y$ via $\operatorname{var}(Y)=E[Y^2]-\left(E[Y]\right)^2$. Note that
the variance is an integer multiple of 
$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\sigma_i^2\right)^{a_i}$
Once again, a similar result holds for $Z$.

For the covariance, we have that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z) &= E[YZ]-E[Y]E[Z]\\
&= E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{a_i+b_i}\right]
- \prod_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i^{a_i}\right] E\left[X_i^{b_i}\right]\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i^{a_i+b_i}\right]
- \prod_{i=1}^n E\left[X_i^{a_i}\right] E\left[X_i^{b_i}\right]\tag{5}
\end{align}
Now, $(2)$ tells us that the second term on the right side of $(5)$ 
is $0$ whenever at least
one of $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n\}$ 
is an odd integer. Eq. $(2)$ also tells us that if at least 
one exponent $a_i+b_i$ in the first term on the right side of $(2)$
is an odd integer, then that first term has value $0$. But, if 
$a_i+b_i$ is odd, then one of $a_i$ and $b_i$ is odd (and the other
is even), and so the second term is $0$ also.
In other words, *if at least one exponent $a_i+b_i$ on the right side of $(5)$ is an odd integer, then $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated .* 
If all the $a_i+b_i$ are even integers,
then $\operatorname{cov}(Y,Z)$ is a positive integer multiple of
$\prod_{i=1}^n \sigma _i^{a_i+b_i}$.

These observations can be encapsulated as follows. Let
$\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ be *binary* $n$-vectors whose
$i$-th components are $a_i \bmod 2$ and $b_i \bmod 2$ respectively.
Then, $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated
if $\mathbf a \neq \mathbf  b$ and positively correlated if
 $\mathbf  a=\mathbf  b$.

---

All of the above assumes that the $a_i$ and the $b_i$ are positive
integers. If we allow the $a_i$ and $b_i$ to take on value $0$ as 
well, then, since $E[X^0] = E[1] = 1$, the above results need to
modified accordingly. One special case of this is of 
independent interest (pun intended).  If $a_ib_i=0$ for all $i$,
then $Y$ and $Z$ are functions of *disjoint* subsets of
$\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\}$ and so are *independent* (and hence
uncorrelated as well even when all the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are even
integers).

Comment: +1 It might help to use a more perspicuous notation. *E.g.*, let $[a,b,\ldots,z]$ stand for $X_1^aX_2^b\cdots X_n^z$ and let $|k|=(k-1)!!$ when $k$ is even, $0$ otherwise. Let $\mathbf{e}_i=[a_i,b_i,\ldots,z_i]$. Then $$\text{Cov}(\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2)=\sigma_1^{a_1+a_2}\sigma_2^{b_1+b_2} \cdots\sigma_n^{z_1+z_2}f(\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2)$$ where $$f(\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2)=|a_1+a_2||b_1+b_2|\cdots|z_1+z_2|-|a_1||b_1| \cdots|z_1|\ |a_2||b_2|\cdots|z_2|.$$ The form of $f$ makes it easy to analyze the sign of the covariance.